# Having problems copying a document into another collection mongoose

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

This is the code i am using to find the document that i need to copy to the other collection:

```
public updateConfigWithType(req: Request, res: Response) {
  configs.findOne({'companyInfo.uniquecompanyid': req.params.id}, function(err, config){
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }
      let swap = new (oldConfigs.model('oldConfigs'))(config)
      swap.save()

      config.parserConfig = req.body;

      config.save(err => {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
          res.json({ data: config });
      });
  });
}


The error message is the following:
 (node:65757) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: {} }"
 (node:65757) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
10:34:34 AM web.1 |  (node:65757) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Not sure how i will fix this. Also i am getting two different errors? What am i missing here please do explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 2 errors are related. I think the error comes from the `swap.save()` because in mongoose if no callback is passed as a parameter the method returns a *Promise*.

You should check the  `config` object you pass in `let swap = new (oldConfigs.model('oldConfigs'))(config)` because it raises the error.

The second message is because you don't catch the promise error. You can write something like that:

```
swap.save().catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just before you wrote i actually tried this `swap.save().then(console.log("swap complete")).catch(err => console.log(err));` What exactly do you mean with `you should check the config object you pass in` check what?

Comment: The promise returns this error `DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: {} }"`. I don't know which config you pass in parameter but it may come from this object. By the way, what is the result of the `swap.save()`?